# Are there any good tutorials for using ShareKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sharekit

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that is easy to understand for ShareKit? I've looked but found nothing. I'm pretty new to Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub wiki for [ShareKit v2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) has a great page titled [Installing ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) that should help you get up and running with the latest incarnation of this project.

The source tree also has an `xcodeproj` file which contains sample code showing how to integrate ShareKit into your own project.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the documentation given in http://getsharekit.com ...after you downloaded and attached to your project open config file and read the comment lines given before each methods in it...it will direct you to correct way...There is no exact tutorial for it...If u got any specific issue then ask a question here..we are ready to answer...

Comment: The [getsharekit.com](http://getsharekit.com) site is tremendously out of date, particularly in code references. A better resource is the ShareKit "reboot" happening directly on [GitHub](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit).

Comment: @RyanWersal But it is having a documentation to edit the sharekit API like how we need to change it for a specific service or to post in a different way.. http://getsharekit.com/docs/

Comment: The documentation found on the [new ShareKit GitHub account](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki) is now more relevant. It also has a discussion as to what happened to the project and what required a "reboot" in the first place. I just don't want the OP to think that the v0.2.1 on [getsharekit.com](http://getsharekit.com) is the latest. Far from it.

Comment: Ya...I agree With you @RyanWersal