# How to add PosterLabs Frames to UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uiimage

My IOS application is same as PosterLabs app (i.e., https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/posterlabs-stylish-collage/id875654777?mt=8) .I should pick multiple images from album and It should save in UIView and when I click a button,all the picked images should parse to next view.If I pick three images after clicking UIButton it should directly go to next view and those 3 images should set to posters with 3 frames.if I Pick 1,2,3,4,5 same process will be followed,Actually my issue is,In gallery I'm able select the images that i needed but how to display picked images in UIView by using scrolling and if I select 3 images how to set them only to 3 frames,if I select 4 how to set them to 4 frames .I'm not getting any idea regarding this.I'm going mad with this.Hope someone helps me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check This Post may use ful  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-project-spotlight-sharekit--mobile-5987

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931458/are-there-any-good-tutorials-for-using-sharekit

Comment: http://amandeepsinghmaan.blogspot.in/2012/04/share-kit-is-widely-used-in-ios.html

Comment: Hi, This is new question please answer me

Comment: I'm not getting this task .you guys please help me to do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my account was banned so I'm editing my older questions..

Comment: @VarunSingh you are not getting my problem know?

Comment: @Suneha Though your question is vague, I understood it partially. This is not a technical question. Its an assignment worth a couple of hours.

Comment: I'm not getting any idea about this.how can we send multiple images to next view at a time and set frames to them